# Passing values from View to Action Method using href = Url.Action()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am trying to passing those values to `Confirmation` action result but i have

> syntax error :missing ;

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("Confirmation", "BookReservation")/?record_locator=' + record_locator +'&hid='@Request.QueryString["hid"] ;

    window.location.href = url;
```

is their any wrong with this code

any advice

Comment: Your single quotes are out of place

Comment: `var url = '@Url.Action("Confirmation", "BookReservation")' +'?record_locator=' + record_locator +'&hid=' + @Request.QueryString["hid"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the url

```
var url = @Url.Action("Confirmation", "BookReservation");
```

And then you add the parameters

```
window.location.href = url + '?record_locator=' + record_locator + '&hid=' + @Request.QueryString["hid"] ;
```